# How to make a Bashscript for SVN Dump

Tags: svn, dump

I have SVN repositories usually in `/var/svn/repos/**foldersX**` , there i had many svn folder's in `repos` folder which I will create using `svnadmin create foldername`
Every time I want to take dump of SVN I do these commands:

```
cd /var/svn/repos
svnadmin dump abcd | gzip -9 > /var/www/html/svn/bck_20_Feb_2014/abcd.dump.gz
svnadmin dump efgh | gzip -9 > /var/www/html/svn/bck_20_Feb_2014/efgh.dump.gz
```

and till the end of the file which is in `/var/svn/repos`,

Is there any way to make script for taking dump of all files and keeping it in `/var/www/html/svn/` from source of `/var/svn/repos` folder?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a script to backup each repository under /var/svn/repos to a directory with today's date under /var/www/html/svn.  Put this script in a text file, make it executable, and add a cron job to run the script daily / weekly / whenever.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE=`date +"%d_%b_%Y"`
BACKUP_DIR=/var/www/html/svn/bck_${DATE}

mkdir -p $BACKUP_DIR

pushd /var/svn/repos    

for d in /var/svn/repos/*
do
  if [ -d "$d" ]
  then
    svnadmin dump $d | gzip -9 > "${BACKUP_DIR}/${d}.dump.gz"
  fi
done

popd
```

I haven't tested it, but this should do what you want.